# Active record toggle method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, toggle

I would like to change value from false to true when users push a button once. And if users push the button again, value should change from true to false.

I tried with the code below but failed. How can I solve this?

☆show.html.erb(group_messages_controller)

```
  <div class="bottom"> 
        <%= link_to"解決！", {:controller =>'group_messages', :action => 'kaiketsu', :id=>@group_message.id}, class: "btn btn-medium btn-default" %></b>
          </div>
```

☆group_messages_controller

```
def show
    if !checklogin? then return end
      @group_message = GroupMessage.find(params[:id])
      @isme = me? @group_message
      @group_message_comment = GroupMessageComment.new
      @group_message_comment = GroupMessage.find(params[:id]).group_message_comments.order("created_at asc").build


      @isme_cmt = me? @group_message_comment
      @gmsc_member_id  = session[:user_id]

      @gm_in = GroupMessage.where(:group_id => @group_message.group_id).order("created_at desc").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)
      @gm_in_one = @gm_in.map{|gm| gm}

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @group_message }
    end
  end


  def kaiketsu
    @group_message= GroupMessage.find(params[:id])
    @group_message.toggle(:kaiketsu)
    @group_message.update_attributes(params[:group_message])
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @group_message }
    end
 end
```

☆schema.rb

```
  create_table "group_messages", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "member_id",                     :null => false
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at",                    :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                    :null => false
    t.integer  "group_id",                      :null => false
    t.integer  "page"
    t.integer  "line"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "username"
    t.boolean  "kaiketsu",   :default => false
  end
```

Comment: Do you get an error or just the value is not being updated?

Answer (score 10):

You should use `toggle!` method instead `toggle`. Because method without `!` doesn't save the changes.

Comment: I had different working of "bang" in my mind but thanks to your answer, I went to check it in detail and having two years of experience working with rails, it was humbling to see my basic concepts redefined :)